# Can't install PyDev for Eclipse Indigo

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation, pydev

I have problem with installation of PyDev in Eclipse Indigo. I used Help -> Install new software -> and http://pydev.org/updates repository. I try it for 3 days yet but it is still not work. First, I got error: unabled to read repository.

[image]

Today, repository was found but during installation of package I got error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Unable to read repository at http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.2.2.2011082312.jar.
>   Read timed out
>   Unable to read repository at http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.2.2.2011082312.jar.
>   Read timed out
>   Unable to read repository at http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev.jython_2.2.2.2011082312.jar.
>   Read timed out

It seems like the repository is out of order. Does somebody know, what to do? Thanks!

Comment: Site might be down for an update? (BTW, I just tried the link and found the .jar)

Comment: Using your distro's package manager to get it might be an alternative as well if the update site is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked and it seems to be working. As a note, a new PyDev release is available (2.2.3).

If it still doesn't work for you, you can try the zip release (see: http://pydev.org/download.html for instructions on getting/installing it).

Answer (score 14):

use http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/site.xml

Comment: This URL worked like a charm. If I use the recommended URL from the PyDev.org website, my installation of eclipse runs into server timeout issues.

Comment: This link works for me time and time again while the official link continues to fail to work. What's the deal?

Comment: Can you bring the most relevant code to this answer. When the link goes dead the answer becomes useless and when I follow that link I have to dig through your repository to understand what I need to do. This Q/A pair is listed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334866/cleanup-500-old-terse-answers-that-either-have-hidden-value-or-indicate-awful-qu/334916#334916). The question is not close-worthy so I rather salvage the answer.

Comment: thanks. This is the only solution for me to install pydev

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but updating eclipse fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Using this url https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/6.3.2 worked for me.

Got this from http://www.pydev.org/updates/